# cann't create task to user using login name

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, tasks

I'm building my workflow for sharepoint 2013 on sharepoint designer and I try to create a task to user using his login and I got this error :

> System.ApplicationException: HTTP 404 {"error": {"code": "- 1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ResourceNotFoundException", "message": {"lang": "fr-FR" Resource can not be found for sp.utilities.utility.ExpandGroupsToPrincipals. "," Innererror ": {" message ":" The resource can not be found for sp.utilities.utility.ExpandGroupsToPrincipals. " .SharePoint.Client.ResourceNotFoundException "," stacktrace ":" to Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestRequestProcessor.GetObjectFromPathRoot (Boolean mainRequestPath, EdmParserNode node, Boolean resourceEndpoint, MethodInformation & METHODINFO) \ u000d \ u000a to Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest .RestRequestProcessor.GetObjectFromPath (Boolean mainRequestPath, String path, String pathForErrorMessage) \ u000d \ u000a to Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestRequestProcessor.Process () \ u000d \ u000a to Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestRequestProcessor.ProcessRequest () \ u000d \ u000a to Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestService.ProcessQuery (Stream inputStream, IList`1 pendingDisposableContainer) "}}} {" X-SharePointHealthScore ": [" 0 "]," SPClientServiceRequestDuration ": [" 47 " ] "SPRequestGuid": [ "8dc91359-318d-46c6-ba01-46f66ea5630d"], "request-id": [ "8dc91359-318d-46c6-ba01-46f66ea5630d"], "X-FRAME-OPTIONS": [ " Sameorigin "," MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices ": [" 15.0.0.4569 "]," X-Content-Type-Options ": [" nosniff "]," X-MS-InvokeApp ": [" 1; RequiredReadOnly "]," Cache-Control ": [" max-age = 0, private "]," Date ": [" Mon, 27 Feb 2017 13:44:23 GMT " IIS \ /8.5 "]," X-AspNet-Version ": [" 4.0.30319 "]," X-Powered-By ": [" ASP.NET "]} to Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Runtime.Subroutine. SubroutineChild.Execute (CodeActivityContext context) to System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute (activityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager BookmarkManager) to System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody (ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager BookmarkManager, resultLocation Location)

Can you help me to fix this.
thank you

Answer (score 0):

please check all language settings. There seems to be an object or browser instance requesting "en-fr" resource. But this culture does not exist - normally it's "fr-FR" or "en-US" / "en-GB".

Comment: thank you for your answer, the culture is fr-FR
I made this mistake because I use google translate to translate the error message

Comment: I updated the culture

Comment: But the problem still exists or not?

Comment: yes the problem still exist